# Django Exception Value: invalid filter error:

Tags: django

I am trying to display a division result in float. So I just arrived to this conclusion that a filter could be helpful, as below:

in views.py:

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()
@register.filter
def div(value, div):
    return round((value / div) * 5, 2)
```

in template:

```
{% for post in Posts %}
        {{ post.likes|div:post.total_like }}
{% endfor %}
```

where `value=post.likes` and `div=post.total_like` but it gives the something like importing error:

> Invalid filter: 'div'

I also tried to put div function/filter in a different file like `mfilteter.py` and import it in template like `{% load mfilteter %}` but didn't work!

Update:

```
- app
  --templates
    ---app
       ----mytemplate.html

  --admin.py
  --mfilteter.py
  --forms.py
  --views.py
  --apps.py
  --urls.py
  --models.py
```

Comment: You do not this in the `views.py`, but under the `templatetags` directory of the app.

Comment: Can you show the "filetree" of your app?

Comment: I just updated the question. Not sure if it is what you need!

Comment: where is the `templatetags`

Comment: Your filetree does not include the `views`, `mfilteter`, etc.?

Comment: yes tried to include them

Comment: `def div(value, div)` I would name the argument something different from the function itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The template tags and template filters are placed under the `templatetags/` directory, so:

```
-app
  --templates
    ---app
       mytemplate.html
  --templatetags/
    __init__.py
    mfilteter.py
  admin.py
  forms.py
  views.py
  apps.py
  urls.py
  models.py
```

You thus construct a `templatetags/` directory under the `app`, and you create an empty `__init__.py` file and you move the `mfilteter` file under the `templatetags` directory.

That being said, you likely do *not* need this, you can simply define a property in your post model:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    # …

    @property
    def like_ratio(self):
        return round(5 * self.likes / self.total_likes(), 2)
```

and use this in the template:

```
{% for post in Posts %}
    {{ post.like_ratio }}
{% endfor %}
```

This is normally better since template should *not* implement "business logic", only "rendering logic". By making it a property, you can use this in views, model admins, etc.

Comment: Thanks. I tried with property but it gives this error: `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'int' and 'method'`

Comment: @ElisaFo: well that means `self.total_likes` is a method?

Comment: @ElisaFo:  then you need to *call* the method, so `self.likes / self.total_likes()`.